# Issue in python after installing Postgres.App

Tags: python, postgresql

I get this error when I try to run a python script that was previously running. 
I recently downloaded Postgres.App and I think this is causing it. I deleted it, but still I get the same error..

```
    import psycopg2 as pg
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 50, in <module>
    from psycopg2._psycopg import BINARY, NUMBER, STRING, DATETIME, ROWID
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.cpython-35m-darwin.so, 2): Library not loaded: /Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.4/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.cpython-35m-darwin.so
  Reason: image not found
```

Do you have any idea what is raising this issue?